# PHP submit POST

Tags: javascript, php

I Created 2 forms and i'm trying to take all of the data and which inside them and email them both in a simple table, however i want that each form will have only 1 header and no matter how much data would be entered or on how many columns it has it will keep adding lines and not headers something like this:
which has only 2 columns but can have 3 in the future:

[image]

So i Created this code to keep it generic as much as possible:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/Jquery.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <title>Test</title>
        <style>
        html
        {
            -webkit-background-size:cover;
            -moz-background-size:cover;
            -o-background-size:cover;
            background-size:cover;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
<body id="body" class="dark-mode">
    <select name="Template_Picker" id="Template_Picker">
        <option value="" Disabled selected hidden>Select Template</option>
        <option value="payment">payment</option>
        <option value="identity">identity</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <div id="Templates_Pages">
        <button class="Template" value="Send" id="Template_Button">Show selected</button>
    </div>
    <div class="vl"></div>
    <form action="test/submit.php" method="post" id="submit_template">
        <center id="output">
        </center>                                                                                                                                    
    </form>
</body>
<script src="test/template.js"></script>
</html>
```

The forms being called by the following id="Template_Picker" with a JS and creating submit button:

```
$(".Template").click(function(){
    template_p = ($('#Template_Picker').val());
    $.get("test\\"+template_p+".php",function(output){
        $("#output").append(output);

        button_exist = document.getElementById('submit');
        if(button_exist == null)
        {
            btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
            btn.innerHTML = "Submit";
            btn.setAttribute("id","submit");
            btn.setAttribute("type","submit");
            btn.setAttribute("name","submit");
            btn.setAttribute("value","Submit");
            btn.setAttribute("class","button-1");
            btn.setAttribute("form","submit_template");
            document.body.appendChild(btn);
        }
        if(document.getElementById("template"))
        {
            document.getElementById("template").id = "template" + document.getElementsByClassName("collapse.toggle").length;
        }
    });
});
```

Forms looks like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="identity" name="DB_Table" value="identity">
<div id="template" class="collapse.toggle" style="padding-left: 276px";>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" name="Full_Name"  >
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="Last_Name"  >
</div>            

<input type="hidden" id="payment" name="DB_Table" value="payment">
<div id="template" class="collapse.toggle" style="padding-left: 276px";>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" name="Full_Name"  >
    <input type="text" placeholder="Credit Card" name="Credit_Card"  >
</div>
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: fyi: The `center` tag is obsolete and is an `output` tag ( or was ) so why use that in the form?

Comment: urls use  a forward slash not backslash so the url you use in the ajax `$.get("test\\"+template_p+".php",` is peculiar

Comment: Also, please include the two templates, `test/payment.php` and `test/identity.php`

Comment: you must NOT use duplicate IDs ( ie: `<div id="template"...` )

Comment: There is an actual `template` tag available in HTML that allows you to add the desired HTML content to be used elsewhere

Comment: @RamRaider - the duplicate template ID, the JS is hanndling it pre-submit, the "center"  is just a tag so i can print the form on my main page nothing more.

Comment: @xxMrPHDxx - I've added both of the forms on my post they were placed the at bottom of the post

Comment: I'd suggest using an `output` tag to output then if that is all it is for. Duplicate IDs are still incorrect regardless of usage.  What is the actual problem above? Are you seeking assistance finishing the code to generate single `headers/column headers` or are there errors with the above?

Comment: @CurrentRedemption So, what's the problem [here](https://i.imgur.com/xCA4xYS.png)?

Comment: @RamRaider - Thank you for being online with me.
Im seeking for assistance to finish the code to generate single headers/column headers

Comment: @xxMrPHDxx - like i wrote to RamRider, i'm looking for a way to submit all the data with via email

Comment: @CurrentRedemption Do you want to submit as html format like `<table>...</table>` or what?

Comment: @xxMrPHDxx - Yes sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As work today has been cancelled I had a spare 1/2 hour and put together a small demo using vanilla javascript and,I think, syntactically valid HTML markup that offers greater flexibility than the original as you can simply add new `template` tags ( with content ) and the javascript should accomodate them accordingly and generate the desired output. The comments throughout ought to help clarify what is going on where...

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
 
 // references to HTML elements
 const oSelect=document.querySelector('select[name="picker"]');
 const oBttn=document.querySelector('input[type="button"][name="template_bttn"]');
 const oForm=document.querySelector('form[name="template"]');
 const oTable=document.querySelector('table[id="output"]');
 const colTemplates=Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('template.source') );
 const oSubBttn=document.querySelector('input[type="button"][name="subdata"]');
 
 // event handler for when the `show selected` button is clicked
 const clickhandler=function(e){
  // only proceed if the SELECT has been changed from the default
  if( oSelect.value != oSelect.childNodes[1].value ){
   // find the template from HTML
   let template=document.querySelector( 'template[ id="'+oSelect.value+'" ]' );
   // add the template HTML to the empty form
   oForm.innerHTML=template.innerHTML;
   
   //assign event handler to button within form
   let bttn=oForm.querySelector('input[type="button"]');
    bttn.addEventListener('click', addcontenthandler );
  }
 };
 
 // clear the form when select menu changes
 const changehandler=function(e){
  oForm.innerHTML='';
 };
 
 // event handler that does the final processing of data when all rows have been added... 
 const submithandler=function(e){
  console.info( oTable.outerHTML );
 };
 
 
 const addcontenthandler=function(e){
  // form elements that are NOT hidden or buttons...
  let col=Array.from( oForm.querySelectorAll('input:not( [type="button"] ):not( [type="hidden"] )') );
  // the type determines which tbody to write content to
  let type=oForm.querySelector('input[ type="hidden" ]').value;
  // the tbody that will be populated according to selection made in the SELECT menu
  let tbody=oTable.querySelector('[ data-name="'+type+'" ]')
  
  // If this particular tbody does NOT have column headers, add them based upon form element names in this form
  if( tbody && !tbody.querySelector('tr[ scope="col" ]') ){
   let tr=document.createElement('tr');
   tr.setAttribute('scope','col');
   tbody.appendChild( tr );
   
   col.forEach( input=>{
    let td=document.createElement('td');
    td.textContent=input.name.replace(/\_/gi,' ');
    tr.appendChild( td );
   });
  }
  // for each input element add it's content to the table...
  tr=document.createElement('tr');
  tbody.appendChild( tr );
  col.forEach( input=>{
   td=document.createElement('td');
   td.textContent=input.value;
   input.value='';
   tr.appendChild( td );
  });   
 };
 
 // add new tbody for each Template found in HTML source & add entry to the select menu
 colTemplates.forEach( template=>{
  let tbody=document.createElement('tbody');
   tbody.dataset.name=template.id;
  oTable.appendChild( tbody );
  oSelect.appendChild( new Option( template.id, template.id ) );
  
 });
 
 
 
 // assign event listeners to various DOM elements
 oBttn.addEventListener('click', clickhandler );
 oSelect.addEventListener('change', changehandler );
 oSubBttn.addEventListener('click', submithandler );
});
```

```css
body, body *{font-family:monospace;box-sizing:border-box}
table{border:1px solid gray;border-collapse:none;width:50%;margin:5rem 0 0 0;padding:1rem;}
td{border:1px dotted gray;padding:1rem;margin:0.1rem;}
tr[scope='col']{background:gray;color:white}
[name='subdata']{padding:1rem;width:50%;}

.pl-276{}
.collapse.toggle{}
```

```html
<form method='post'>
 <select name='picker'>
  <option selected hidden disabled>Please Select Template
  <!-- other options are populated dynamically -->
 </select>
 <input type='button' name='template_bttn' value='Show Selected' />
</form>

<form method='post' name='template'><!-- content will be added here dynamically depending upon chosen template --></form>
<table id='output'></table>
<input type='button' name='subdata' value='Submit generated data' />

<!-- you can add as many `TEMPLATES` as you like with as many `INPUT ELEMENTS` as you like -->
<template id='identity' class='source'>
 <input type='hidden' name='DB_Table' value='identity' />
 <div class='collapse.toggle pl-276'>
  <input type='text' placeholder='Full Name' name='Full_Name' />
  <input type='text' placeholder='Last Name' name='Last_Name' />
 </div>
 <input type='button' value='Add Content' />
</template>

<template id='payment' class='source'>
 <input type='hidden' name='DB_Table' value='payment' />
 <div class='collapse.toggle pl-276'>
  <input type='text' placeholder='Full Name' name='Full_Name' />
  <input type='text' placeholder='Credit Card' name='Credit_Card' />
 </div>
 <input type='button' value='Add Content' />
</template>

<template id='banana' class='source'>
 <input type='hidden' name='DB_Table' value='banana' />
 <div class='collapse.toggle pl-276'>
  <input type='text' placeholder='Banana Colour' name='Banana_Colour' />
  <input type='text' placeholder='Banana Shape' name='Banana_Shape' />
  <input type='text' placeholder='Banana Weight' name='Banana_Weight' />
 </div>
 <input type='button' value='Add Content' />
</template>
```

Comment: Hey RamRider!
Thank you so much for taking time to build up a solution for my problem! O.o
much appriciation! helped me a lot!